# pass URL on to Contact form

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

**Situation:**
A user is viewing a web-page using the contact option provided. Upon clicking 'Contact', I'd like to pass the URL of the currently viewed page as text into a field of that contact form.

The starting point is any HTML page (page-xy.html).
The existing contact-form is written in PHP, HTML and CSS (contact.php) and does function fine.
I assume a Javascript may help to accomplish this procedure.

Upon clicking the 'Contact' button, this Javascript command reads the current URL: 
`var strReferrer=window.location.href;`

The **question is** how to pass this variable 'strReferrer' on to 'contact.php' that is being opened?
In the following the variable should be inserted into the message text field for example.
I'd rather not use a cookie for this.

Hope someone has suggestions leading to the solution, thanks.

[My goal is just about the reverse of the problem described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283845/passing-a-variable-from-php-to-javascript-and-on-to-an-html-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I have implemented.

In any HTML page with a contact option, call a simple script as stated below.
In case JS is not available the contact form opens via 'href' and of course without the originating URL.

```
<a href="/contact/contact-form.php" title="send an eMail" onclick="return(contact())">Contact the author</a>
```

... that puts the string of the current URL into 'strReferrer' and opens a new window with your contact-form.php

```
<script>
var strReferrer = location.href;
function contact() {
window.open("/contact/contact-form.php?sourceURL="+strReferrer);
return false;}
</script>
```

PHP queries the string with 'strReferrer' and keeps it in '$params'.
in contact-form.php:

```
//get the URL from the originating page (where this form has been called from)
$params  = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
...
...
// Insert '$params' into the text as part of the text to be eMailed.
// the eMail Content Header for the recipient
$_POST["text"] = $_POST["send"]["author"]." with e-mail address: ".$_POST["send"]["mail"]." sent the msg below: \n <$params> \n \n $texto";
```

Now you know the page-url your visitors have decided to contact you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a hidden input field.

```
<form ...>
    <!-- Your contact form goes here -->
    <input type="hidden" id="strReferrer" name="strReferrer" value="whatever" />
</form>
```

You can have javascript set the value if you want.

Comment: What would the script be like? somehow I have to get the URL from the previous page and pass it on into this form.

Comment: Somehow I need to store the value of the URL of the page that is calling this page with the email form.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line in form and you give referer at form data prelucration.

```
<input type="hidden" id="referer" name="referer" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

Comment: That returns the URL of the page containing this form for sending an email.  What I need is the URL of the previous page, the one that is calling the page with this email form. And eventually write that value into the email itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving a similar problem here

I'm using this code to capture the page url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var segments = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var toDelete = [];
for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    if (segments[i].length < 1) {
        toDelete.push(i);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < toDelete.length; i++) {
    segments.splice(i, 1);
}
var filename = segments[segments.length - 1];
console.log(filename);
document.write(filename);
</script>
```

but how to i put it inside a contact form textbox?
(I'm using a wordpress contact form plugin)

see here: https://nationalland.co.uk/tw31sp